# Android SAXParser working on 2.2.1 but not on 2.2

Tags: android, xml, saxparser

I have these classes and functions:

**Read preferences from XML**

```
private void readPreferences(InputSource is) {
PrefsFetcher pf = new PrefsFetcher();
prefs = pf.getPreferences(is);
if (prefs == null) {
    Log.d(Constants.TAG, "prefs == null");
} 
// save to DB
savePreferences();
}
```

**Preferences fetcher**

```
public class PrefsFetcher {

public ArrayList<Preferences> getPreferences(InputSource is) {

    ArrayList<Preferences> prefs = null;

    try {
            SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xmlReader = saxParser.getXMLReader();

        PrefsHandler handler = new PrefsHandler();
        xmlReader.setContentHandler(handler);
        Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Parsing XML");
        xmlReader.parse(is);
        prefs = handler.getPreferences();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return prefs;
}
```

}

**Preferences Handler**

```
public class PrefsHandler extends DefaultHandler {

private static final String PREFERENCES = "preferences";
private static final String DNI = "id";
private static final String FREQUENCY = "interval";
private static final String PHONE_NUMBER = "phoneNumber";
private static final String SERVER_ADDRESS = "serverAddress";
private static final String SERVER_PORT = "serverPort";
private static final String SERVER_PREF_ADDRESS = "prefAddress";
private static final String SERVER_PREF_PORT = "prefPort";

private boolean idChars;
private boolean frequencyChars;
private boolean phoneNumberChars;
private boolean serverAddressChars;
private boolean serverPortChars;
private boolean prefAddressChars;
private boolean prefPortChars;

boolean startPreferences;

private int numPrefs;
private Preferences pref;
private final ArrayList<Preferences> prefs;

public PrefsHandler(){
    this.prefs = new ArrayList<Preferences>();
}

@Override
public void startDocument(){
}

@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes atts) {

    //Log.d(Constants.TAG, "XML localName: " + localName + " qName: " + qName);

    if (localName.equals(PREFERENCES)) {
        this.startPreferences = true;
        this.pref = new Preferences();
    }
    if (this.startPreferences){
        if (localName.equals(FREQUENCY)) {
            this.frequencyChars = true;
        } else if (localName.equals(PHONE_NUMBER)) {
            this.phoneNumberChars = true;
        } else if (localName.equals(DNI)) {
            this.idChars = true;
        } else if (localName.equals(SERVER_ADDRESS)) {
            this.serverAddressChars = true;
        } else if (localName.equals(SERVER_PORT)) {
            this.serverPortChars = true;
        } else if (localName.equals(SERVER_PREF_ADDRESS)) {
            this.prefAddressChars = true;
        } else if (localName.equals(SERVER_PREF_PORT)) {
            this.prefPortChars = true;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void endDocument(){}

@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) {
    if (localName.equals(PREFERENCES)){
        this.startPreferences = false;
        this.numPrefs++;
        this.prefs.add(this.pref);
    }
    if (this.startPreferences){
        if (localName.equals(FREQUENCY)) {
            this.frequencyChars = false;
        } else if (localName.equals(PHONE_NUMBER)) {
            this.phoneNumberChars = false;
        } else if (localName.equals(DNI)) {
            this.idChars = false;
        } else if (localName.equals(SERVER_ADDRESS)) {
            this.serverAddressChars = false;
        } else if (localName.equals(SERVER_PORT)) {
            this.serverPortChars = false;
        } else if (localName.equals(SERVER_PREF_ADDRESS)) {
            this.prefAddressChars = false;
        } else if (localName.equals(SERVER_PREF_PORT)) {
            this.prefPortChars = false;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void characters(char [] ch, int start, int length) {
    String chString = "";
    if (ch != null) {
        chString = new String (ch, start, length);
    }

    if (this.startPreferences) {
        //Log.d(Constants.TAG, "chString: " + chString);
        if (this.idChars) {
            this.pref.setId(chString);
        } else if (this.frequencyChars) {
            this.pref.setFrequency(chString);
        } else if (this.phoneNumberChars) {
            this.pref.setPhoneNumber(chString);
        } else if (this.serverAddressChars) {
            this.pref.setServerAddress(chString);
        } else if (this.serverPortChars) {
            this.pref.setServerPort(chString);
        } else if (this.prefAddressChars) {
            this.pref.setPrefAddress(chString);
        } else if (this.prefPortChars) {
            this.pref.setPrefPort(chString);
        }
    }
}

public ArrayList<Preferences> getPreferences(){
    Log.d(Constants.TAG, "prefs length: " + prefs.size());
    return this.prefs;
}

public String getAttributeValue(String attName, Attributes atts){
    String result = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < atts.getLength(); i++){
        String thisAtt = atts.getLocalName(i);
        if (attName.equals(thisAtt)){
            result = atts.getValue(i);
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

}

If I run this code on the emulator or on a HTC Wildfire with 2.2.1, it works well, and I am able to save those preferences on the database. However, when I run it on a Samsung Galaxy S with 2.2, I does return a null value at readPreferences function.

Is it a bug on 2.2 or I am doing something wrong?

Thank you for your help,

Answer (score 0):

> Is it a bug on 2.2 or I am doing something wrong?

I don't know if there's a bug in 2.2, but you're doing at least one thing wrong.

The `characters` method can be called multiple times by the parser, partially supplying the characters on each call.  Your `characters` method will only work if you get lucky and it's only called once.

To properly deal with characters in SAX, you need to (for each tag where you need to collect characters) initialize a buffer in the `startElement` method, collect characters into the buffer in the `characters` method, and get the result in the `endElement` method.